# Excel 2007 using VBA write formula to merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values starting at G11 and extending a variable length down column G. I have a string array which contains the addresses of ranges of the G column data to be averaged. In the H column starting at H11 I have merged cells where I want the averaged values to appear. The number of G column cells to be averaged together also varies. The following code I tried failed since the formula was entered as is, rather than having the ranges(i) array value placed into the formula.

```
For i = 0 To range_num
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(ranges(i))"
Next i
```

ranges() contains the ranges (in string form) to be averaged. And for example:

`ranges(i) = "G11:G15"`

for`i = 0` and `range_num` is the number of averages that will be done.

Each G column value is only included in 1 average, each group of values to be averaged is consecutive, and each group is directly to the left of the merged cell where I want the average to appear. Does anyone have some insight on how I could better format my code to achieve this? Any ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & ranges(i) & ")"` ?

Comment: It would help if you attached a snippet of the worksheet to help visualize the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the formula is entering 'as is' is because you'd need to concatenate it into the string.

```
For i = 0 To range_num
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & ranges(i) & ")"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted correctly, you are looking for a code snippet that will loop through a range of cells and set the formula based on the literal string found in another cell.  Try the following:

```
sub SetCellFormulas()

dim sWS as worksheet
dim aCell as range
dim aRange as range
dim Lrow as long

set sws = thisworkbook.sheets("yourworksheetname")

'*** Locate last cell with values in column G
lrow = sws.Range("G11").end(xldown).row

'*** Set range to loop through
set arange = sws.Range("G11:G" & Lrow)
for each acell in arange
  '*** set formula of cell 1 to the left of G to the concatenated formula
  aCell.offset(0,1).formula = "=AVERAGE(" & acell.value & ")"
next acell

end sub
```

Comment: I have [formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.